# is it possible that the hypersurface $A$ has limit points on the Riemann surface $X$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The hypersurface is defined to be the analytic subvariety of codimension 1, with the dimension defined to be the smooth part of it( the dimension of the manifold.)

A typical example is a set of isolated points on the Riemann surface, **is it possible that the hypersurface $A$ has limit points on the Riemann surface $X$?**

---

I think it can not, since if exists a limit point, then any neighborhood $U\subset X$ around that point must contain infinitely many points in the hypersurface such that $Z(f_1,...,f_n) = A\cap U$ set of $f_i$ vanishing on infinite many points inside that small neiborhood, therefore they must be zero by the identity principle, therefore it will implies $U\subset A$, and it's codimension zero.Which is impossible for the hypersurface. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Ok, I found the formal statement that : analytic subset of Riemann surface all points are smooth, therefore it can not have limit point.

Comment: And you can see the set of points are union of single point set which are locally finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Riemann surface, you can argue as follows, using theory of holomorphic functions in one variable:

Suppose $A = V(f_1, \dotsc, f_n) \subset X$, and $x \in X$ is a limit point. Then choose a small neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, with a biholomorhic chart $\varphi: B_1(0) \to U$, such that $\varphi(0) = x$. Then $g_i = f_i \circ \varphi$ are holomorphic functions on $B_1(0)$, and by assumption $0$ is a limit point of the zeroes of the $g_i$. But by complex analysis, any holomorphic function whose zeroes have a limit point in the interior of the domain, is the zero map. So $g_i \equiv 0$ for all $i$, and hence $f_i \equiv 0$. But then $A = X$, contradicting the assumption that it is a hypersurface.

Comment: Thank you red_trumpet, I have worked out this problem. And   Chirka E.M's several complex variable books, have several propositions about it.